# useOptimistic hook bug

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting a weird behavior when using the useOptimistic hook from React.

Running:
"next": "^14.0.4" with app router.

When I click the button I get 2 console log outputs instantly.

In the first log I can see the optimistic result:

```
{
    "__typename": "GuideBlocksFormWebsite",
    "id": "1",
    "value": true,
    "pending": true
}
```

And then instantly directly after it's reverted to the init state as seen in the second log (not the desired state as the value should be updated to true):

```
{
    "__typename": "GuideBlocksFormWebsite",
    "id": "1",
    "value": false
}
```

SSRPage:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server'
import { Form } from './Form'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

const SSRPage = async () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore)

  const { data: form } = await supabase.from('forms_progress').select()

  return (
    <>
      <Form initFormData={form} />
    </>
  )
}

export default SSRPage
```

initFormData looks like this:

```
form: [
  {
    id: '97b1672d-b119-473e-958c-8d1c0902fc09',
    'mrkoll.se': false,
    'eniro.se': false,
    'merinfo.se': false,
    'hitta.se': false,
    'ratsit.se': false,
    is_completed: false,
    created_at: '2023-12-05T23:26:54.592581+00:00',
    updated_at: '2023-12-05T23:26:54.592581+00:00',
    'birthday.se': false
  }
]
```

Form:

```
'use client'

import { useOptimistic, useState } from 'react'
import TickButton from './TickButton'

const keysToRender = ['mrkoll.se', 'eniro.se', 'merinfo.se', 'hitta.se', 'ratsit.se', 'birthday.se']

export const Form = ({ initFormData }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initFormData[0])
  const [optimisticTick, addOptimisticTick] = useOptimistic(form, (state, newValue) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      [newValue.key]: newValue.value,
    }
  })

  const renderButtons = () => {
    return keysToRender.map((key) => (
      <TickButton
        key={key}
        id={key}
        value={optimisticTick[key]}
        addOptimisticTick={addOptimisticTick}
      />
    ))
  }

  return <>{optimisticTick && renderButtons()}</>
}
```

TickButton:

```
'use client'

import { useTransition } from 'react'
import useGuideForm from '@/app/hooks/useGuideForm'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const TickButton = ({ id, value, addOptimisticTick }) => {
  const { updateFormsProgress } = useGuideForm()
  const [, startTransition] = useTransition()
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleOnClick = async () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      addOptimisticTick({ key: id, value: true, pending: true })
    })

    await updateFormsProgress({
      [id]: true,
    })

    router.refresh()
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick} disabled={value === true}>
      {value ? 'Ready' : 'Confirm'}
    </button>
  )
}

export default TickButton
```

updateFormsProgress:

```
  const updateFormsProgress = async (data: unknown) => {
    try {
      if (user) {
        const { error } = await supabase
          .from('forms_progress')
          .update(data)
          .eq('id', user?.id as string)

        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error.message)
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      captureException(error)
    }
  }
```

Uploaded video here of the behavior:
[video](https://jmp.sh/fqrwdFLv)

The flow:

- Button has value false, the data is fetched during SSR and passed on to the useOptimistic hook as the init value.
- Button is clicked the first time, and the optimistic value flickers.
- Button returns to false value after flickering.
- Button is clicked a second time, value is correctly set to true.

Do you have any clues to what's going on here?

Comment: There's a lot of code here, it's hard to see what's relevant. Can you produce a minimal piece of code that still reproduces the problem?

Comment: @ruakh i've simplified the code

Comment: Thanks! But there's still . . . a lot. I find it hard to imagine that every single one of those functions is needed in order to trigger this bug.

Comment: BTW, [the useOptimistic documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useOptimistic) gives no indication of how it decides that the async action is complete and it should go back to just returning its first argument. Based on your description of what you're experiencing, I wonder if it's deciding that your action is complete earlier than you're expecting it to?

Comment: @ruakh "I wonder if it's deciding that your action is complete earlier" i think this might be what's happening. it's a logical assumption.

Comment: Judging from [this blog post](https://barrymichaeldoyle.com/blog/use-optimistic), the way you indicate that the async action is complete is by changing the first argument to `useOptimistic`. So you probably need to use `useMemo` to avoid spuriously modifying that argument.

Comment: i've simplified the code again. should be easy to recreate now. i've included the shape of the initFormData so it's easy to mock the db call as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue while attempting to implement the useOptimistic hook without resorting to server actions, revalidateTag, and 'no-cache'. While I can't pinpoint why your code isn't functioning as expected, it appears as though it should. I'm not sure if it potentially could be some kind of caching issue.

However, a potential resolution could involve the following steps:

1. Implement a server action:

```
'use server'

import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache'

export const mutateFormProgress = async (keyToUpdate, rowId) => {
  await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/form-progress?rowId=${rowId}`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        keytoUpdate,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    }
  )

  revalidateTag('form-progress')
}
```

2. Modify the onClick handler:

```
const handleOnClick = async () => {
  startTransition(() => {
    addOptimisticTick({ key: id, value: true, pending: true })
  })

  await mutateFormProgress(keyToUpdate, rowId)
}
```

3. Perform the fetch call on the SSR page:

```
const response = await fetch(
  `http://localhost:3000/api/form-progress}`,
  {
    cache: 'no-cache',
    next: {
      tags: ['form-progress'],
    },
  }
)
const formData = await response.json()
```

Additionally, it's essential to create an API endpoint, e.g., api/form-progress, with endpoints for both fetching (GET) and mutating (POST) data from the database table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you're updating the original state that is being passed into your useOptimistic hook, not just calling the addOptimisticTick function...

I think react is waiting for the original state (Tick) to update because thats why you would want to call useOptimistic, but the original state is not updating so it stops using the optimistic value and reverts to the old state.

So you would need to call the update state function for the prop that is being passed into the component, useOptimistic isn't a replacement for that prop value

```
const [optimisticTick, addOptimisticTick] = useOptimistic(
    tick, 
    (prevTick, newTick) => {
        ...prevTick,
        ...newTick,
        pending: true
    }
)

const handleOnClick = (event) => {
    startTransition(() => {
      addOptimisticTick({value: true});
      // you need to update the original tick that was passed as the prop
     
      // Generally you make some sort of API call here
      // const tickResponse = await GENERIC_API_CALL(event);
      // tickResponse will be the updated tick so = {value: true}

      // setTick((prev) => { ...prev, ...tickResponse} // pending will go back to false or undefined but value will update
    });

    handleTickPage(event)
  }
```

Comment: nope, possible to use the hook like this as well. as you can see i'm providing the default value during the init of the hook. and then i'm supplying the update fn when calling the hook. you can do it like this or you can pass a reducer as the second arg during init.


the api call is:
handleTickPage(event). this is ssr -> client component. no useState used.

Comment: @octavemirbeau okay, so the syntax aside.

You still need to update the value of tick that you're passing as a prop to TickButton somehow. I can't tell by what you posted how where 'Tick' prop comes from but it must be a state value for useOptimistic to work. If it is a static value it will not work.

And after you call the addOptimisticTick function, you need to update the value of "Tick" as it is being watched by the hook. If "Tick" never changes or isn't in state, then the hook will not work

Comment: the init value comes from a fetch call to the db server side, and then after the update call to the db for the table forms_progress, i run router.refresh(), which will trigger the server to fetch the new data. i've updated the code extract now so it's clear.

Comment: logging form/mergedData after router.refresh() shows the desired output. which means that useOptimistic hook should get the refreshed data as well. yet i have this laggy behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing router.refresh() call in your handleOnClick function. I think this call might be causing the component to re-render, and since the data is fetched during SSR and passed on to the useOptimistic hook as the initial value, the state might be getting reset to its initial value.

Try doing this instead:

```
const handleOnClick = async () => {
  startTransition(() => {
    addOptimisticTick({ key: id, value: true, pending: true })
  })

  await updateFormsProgress({
    [id]: true,
  })

  // Fetch the new data
  const { data: newForm } = await supabase.from('forms_progress').select()
  
  // Update the state with the new data
  setForm(newForm[0])
}
```

Comment: you want to refresh for this exact reason. to get the new data.
if you had read the comments before posting you would have seen this:
"logging form/mergedData after router.refresh() shows the desired output. which means that useOptimistic hook should get the refreshed data as well. yet i have this laggy behaviour."